# How to use vpnkit with minikube on mac

Tags: docker, minikube, hyperkit

There are many question around this topic, but not the specific info I am after.

Host OS is Mac, and recently had to uninstall Docker Desktop due to their licensing change. So instead we have moved to minikube, and it is all working great with VirtualBox driver.

But ideally we would like to use the hyperkit driver, as it requires less resources than virtualbox, and is (anecdotally) faster. This also all works great until we connect to our VPN (using cisco anyconnect) and then all outbound networking from within the minikube VM stops working. e.g.

```
k8> minikube ssh "traceroute 8.8.8.8"
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  host.minikube.internal (192.168.64.1)  0.154 ms  0.181 ms  0.151 ms
 2  *  *  *
```

Everything else is is fine, inbound networking via ingress is all good. And maven-docker-plugin is happily creating images with the minikube docker daemon. Just nothing outbound.

So figured I'd try to work with VPNKit as I have read it is meant to address this issue. But cannot find a lot of detailed documentation, and so am struggling.

We have tried starting VPNKit with minimal config:

```
vpnkit --ethernet /tmp/vpkit-ethernet.socket --debug
```

And then attempt to start minikube, but it fails:

```
k8> minikube delete
  Deleting "minikube" in hyperkit ...
  Removed all traces of the "minikube" cluster.
k8> minikube start --driver=hyperkit --hyperkit-vpnkit-sock=/tmp/vpnkit-ethernet.socket
  minikube v1.25.1 on Darwin 10.15.7
✨  Using the hyperkit driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Creating hyperkit VM (CPUs=2, Memory=6000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
  Deleting "minikube" in hyperkit ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: hyperkit crashed! command line:
  hyperkit loglevel=3 console=ttyS0 console=tty0 noembed nomodeset norestore waitusb=10 systemd.legacy_systemd_cgroup_controller=yes random.trust_cpu=on hw_rng_model=virtio base host=minikube
  Creating hyperkit VM (CPUs=2, Memory=6000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
  Failed to start hyperkit VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: hyperkit crashed! command line:
  hyperkit loglevel=3 console=ttyS0 console=tty0 noembed nomodeset norestore waitusb=10 systemd.legacy_systemd_cgroup_controller=yes random.trust_cpu=on hw_rng_model=virtio base host=minikube

❌  Exiting due to PR_HYPERKIT_CRASHED: Failed to start host: creating host: create: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: hyperkit crashed! command line:
  hyperkit loglevel=3 console=ttyS0 console=tty0 noembed nomodeset norestore waitusb=10 systemd.legacy_systemd_cgroup_controller=yes random.trust_cpu=on hw_rng_model=virtio base host=minikube
  Suggestion: Hyperkit is broken. Upgrade to the latest hyperkit version and/or Docker for Desktop. Alternatively, you may choose an alternate --driver
  Related issues:
    ▪ https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6079
    ▪ https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5780
```

And in the vpnkit log we see:

```
time="2022-02-14T06:07:57Z" level=debug msg="usernet: accepted vmnet connection"
time="2022-02-14T06:07:57Z" level=warning msg="Uwt: Pipe.listen: rejected ethernet connection: EOF"
time="2022-02-14T06:08:07Z" level=debug msg="usernet: accepted vmnet connection"
time="2022-02-14T06:08:07Z" level=warning msg="Uwt: Pipe.listen: rejected ethernet connection: EOF"
```

So kind of implies something is not right with how I started vpnkit. Have played with IP args to ensure it all matches, but does not help.

My guess is that the `--ethernet=path` arg is not the right type of socket. I have seen there is also `--vsock-path=path` but specifying this does not appear to create the socket file like `--ethernet=path` does. Do I have to create this some other way?

Or are there other config options I need to mess with. e.g. I thought `--gateway-forwards=path` could help, but can find no documentation on file format or contents.

So, I guess two main questions:

- Is what we are trying even possible? Is it the the right way to go about it? Or is it much more complicated than simply running the `vpnkit` command?
- If we are on the right track, does anyone have experience with this, and know how to set up the socket for minikube+vpnkit+hyperkit? What args, config, or other setup is required?

And just to note: `--hyperkit-vpnkit-sock=auto` is not an option for us, as we do not have docker installed, and so the docker socket file does not exist.

And just in case its a version issue:

```
k8> minikube version
minikube version: v1.25.1
commit: 3e64b11ed75e56e4898ea85f96b2e4af0301f43d
k8> vpnkit --version
854498c13b1884d4a48d84f3569eb34681af2126
k8> hyperkit -v
hyperkit: 0.20200908

Homepage: https://github.com/docker/hyperkit
License: BSD
```

Comment: Ok, it is kind of working when I use newer version (v0.20210107) of hyperkit (built from source - homebrew still on older one). I say "kind of" because outbound network kin of comes and goes, and lots of `no route` errors in the vpnkit log. Got the vpnkit from most recent stable on CI tool linked to from github page. Will play with more version combinations, as the ones I was using we about a year apart.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? I'm having similar issues, but struggling to build the latest version of Hyperkit from source.

Comment: It would work for a bit, and then outbound networking would stop. Think the issue was with `vpnkit` (most likely how we were using it). Hyperkit on its own worked ok with VPN off, but not practical for our team, VPN almost always on. We gave up and settled on virtualbox backend.